# Selecting actionbarmenu item Selendroid

Tags: selenium, selendroid

I'm learning selendroid and I'd like to select a option from a action bar menu. I'm able to open the menu doing

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//ActionMenuView")).click();
```

But I'm not able to find how to click the item.

[image]

I think the OverflowMenuButton is the item to select but I can't get the reference from the inspector

[image]

Anyone so kind to help me ?

Thanks in advance.

Regards

Comment: Just a guess: `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//ActionMenuView/OverflowMenuButton")).click();`

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, I've tried but I'm getting "element was not found", so I think is not valid.